# Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource Spring/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I am getting these exceptions. Earlier my code was working fine. I don't know what happened now :P..... Please help me resolve the issue listed below.

**Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource** 
I looked for this issue but couldn't find the solution. Please help

**Exceptions**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mapAcctDatasourceManger' defined in class path resource [spring/agent-common.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mapAcctDatasourceDao' while setting bean property 'mapAcctDatasourceDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mapAcctDatasourceDao' defined in class path resource [spring/agent-common.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/dbconfig.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: com.receivablesradius.deductions.model.InvoiceClaimXRef
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
    at com.scraper.AgentLauncher.getDynamicContext(AgentLauncher.java:278)
    at com.scraper.AgentLauncher.main(AgentLauncher.java:652)
    at com.highradius.util.AgentLauncherTest.main(AgentLauncherTest.java:17)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mapAcctDatasourceDao' defined in class path resource [spring/agent-common.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/dbconfig.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: com.receivablesradius.deductions.model.InvoiceClaimXRef
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:106)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1325)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1086)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 17 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [spring/dbconfig.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: com.receivablesradius.deductions.model.InvoiceClaimXRef
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:322)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Association references unmapped class: com.receivablesradius.deductions.model.InvoiceClaimXRef
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder.bindCollectionSecondPass(HbmBinder.java:2380)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder$CollectionSecondPass.secondPass(HbmBinder.java:2662)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1130)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration.secondPassCompile(AnnotationConfiguration.java:324)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1115)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:717)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.AbstractSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractSessionFactoryBean.java:211)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 34 more
```

Comment: have you gone through the Exception cause?

Comment: Issue might be with your mapping. Check it once

Answer (score 1):

This model InvoiceClaimXRef is unmapped , check if your project missing the map xml ,or your configure xml file do not import the model map xml.